# Cast timestamp to String in presto MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, presto

How can I cast a timestamp column to string to do wildcard operations in Presto MySQL?

I have used the following command:
`CAST(time_at as char(100)) LIKE '2019-10-31%'`

Getting an error:
`Presto error: TYPE_MISMATCH: line 120:8: Cannot cast timestamp to char(100)`

Comment: Presto is SQL, but it's not MySQL AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VARCHAR`:

```sql
select CAST(timestamp '2019-10-31 01:00' as VARCHAR) LIKE '2019-10-31%'
```

Also note that checking that timestamp belongs to concreate day can be achieved via [`date_trunk`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc):

```sql
select date_trunc('day', timestamp '2019-10-31 01:00') = date '2019-10-31';
```